# How to reset the brightness of a buffered image

Tags: java

Okay so I'm trying to change the brightness of an image for a short period of time, and then reset the brightness. However when I try to do this it makes the image to dark and not the original color. Here is my code

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/image.png"));
private void changeBrightness(){
    RescaleOp bright = new RescaleOp(1.5f, 0, null);
    RescaleOp normal = new RescaleOp(0.66f, 0, null);
    image = bright.filter(image, image);
    wait(0.5);
    image = normal.filter(image, image);
}
```

When this method gets called the brightness changes fine, but it's the changing back that things get weird. The image is becomes to dark. I have the brightness scale for the normal to 0.66, because 2/3 times 1.5 equals one which is what I want. If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong I would appreciate that a lot.

Comment: Keep a reference to the original?

Comment: I suggest to create a clone of the `BufferedImage` and increase the brightness there. So you can keep the original version and don't have a loss of quality by manipulating the picture twice.

Comment: Thanks I don't know why I did not think of that it seems obvious to me now. Thanks a lot it really helped!

Comment: @Tom It would be easier not to pass the `image` as the destination value (passing `null` instead) and assigning the result to new `BufferedImage` variable...no need to create more stuff, let the filter deal with it ... IMHO :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you want to keep a reference to the original image, so instead of

```
image = bright.filter(image, image);
```

You could do...

```
BufferedImage filtered = bright.filter(image, null);
```